# How to increase JVM stack size for the app in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, jvm, stack-overflow

How can I increase the stack size (like "-Xss4m") in Android Studio?
I mean the stack size for my app (both for a virtual test device in AS and for any physical device where the app will be installed), not for AS or the Gradle build process.

I did not find any AS setting or Gradle script to do this.